# Retrofit throwing error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY From arraylist to list?

Tags: java, retrofit

Hi I am having problems parsing some json. I have looked at some other solutions on Stackoverflow but not having much luck with my problem. im trying to get a a simple recyleview to work. Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Json File Type

```
[
  {
    "name": "Javi",
    "birthdate": "2018-10-17T00:00:00",
    "id": 25
  },
```

Interface

```
public interface UsuariosInterface {

@GET("User")
    Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>> obtenerListaUsuarios();
}
```

Separated Interface

```
public class UsuariosRespuesta {

private ArrayList<Usuarios> results;


public ArrayList<Usuarios> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(ArrayList<Usuarios> results) {
    this.results = results;
}}
```

Model

```
public class Usuarios {

private String name;
private String birthdate;
    private Integer id;
}
```

Request method

```
  UsuariosInterface service = retrofit.create(UsuariosInterface.class);
    Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>> usuariosRespuestaCall= service.obtenerListaUsuarios();

    usuariosRespuestaCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>> call, Response<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                UsuariosRespuesta usuariosRespuesta = response.body();
                ArrayList<Usuarios> listaUsuarios = usuariosRespuesta.getResults();
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I can understand that the error is saying the data is an array and it should start with an object but I cant work it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the direct list without any key then just pass list in your interface like

```
@GET("User")
Call<UsuariosRespuesta> obtenerListaUsuarios();
```

but you are getting a whole object without the key as you are doing the response should be like this {[{},{},{},.....{}]}

```
 @GET("User")
   Call<UsuariosRespuesta> obtenerListaUsuarios();}
```

above situation need when your data is coming like this

{
[  {
   },
   {
   }
]
}   upper object refrtence this `UsuariosRespuesta`  but you are getting directly array [{},{},{}...] without key then need `Arraylist` in response.

and serialized your POJO too.

```
    public class Usuarios {
@field:SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@field:SerializedName("birthdate")
private String birthdate;
@field:SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: Added the json file type. its is an object not an array, Just changed some lines and thats my problem

Comment: @Delug3 you are getting `Array` type object.

Comment: working on it, dont know what to change yet. Fixed my interface with an array list, but now having problems in my response. I am mixing some types I guess

Comment: are you getting any key outside Array?

Comment: no. I have updated my question, with the json file so you can see it. I am using an arraylist in my separated interface, but I do have now some imcompatibles types problems:   incompatible types: Call<UsuariosRespuesta> cannot be converted to Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>>

Comment: I think  your class is not serialized `Usuarios `. see updated code. and also make the change in calling retrofit with ` Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>>`  and interface too.

Comment: @Delug3 definetly you will get incompatible type. you have to change everywhere `Call<UsuariosRespuesta>` to  `Call<ArrayList<UsuariosRespuesta>> ` , also change in interface and where you are calling retorfit.

Comment: Serialized and changed to arraylist.  I just have an incompatible type in the last line of my response. See updated code in my first question. And thank you for helping me , seriously